# How to combine two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a merged Pandas dataframe in the following format

| index | value_x | value_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan |
| 3 | -1 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 | nan |
| 5 | nan | 6 |
| 6 | -1 | nan |
| 7 | -1 | 6 |
| 8 | nan | nan |

Since the original dataframes have the `value` field, therefore `value_x` and `value_y` column is gnerated during the merge process. I would like to merge the two columns so the final column would look like:

| index | value_x | value_y | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | nan | 3 |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 | nan | 6 |
| 5 | nan | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | -1 | nan | -1 |
| 7 | nan | 6 | 6 |
| 8 | nan | nan | nan |

In addition, I would like to know if I could avoid the column combining process during the merge process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max`

```
df["value"] = df[["value_x", "value_y"]].max(axis=1)
```

as this will pick the non-nan value for each row. For this question:

> In addition, I would like to know if I could avoid the column combining process during the merge process?

the answer depends on what the two dataframes were before the merge.

Comment: Thanks. Initially I use apply and max should be simpler and faster